# How can I use SVG Masks to make a Luma Mask?

Tags: svg, alpha, mask, blend, compositing

I want to make a Luma-Mask (Matte) in SVG.
In other words I want to mask a layer to the luminance channel (acquired from the RGB channels) of a different layer.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Luminance masks](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/masking.html#mask-property) are a new feature of the SVG 2 specification. They have been implemented in [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=793617) and [Webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97011).

Comment: Yes, I was just making sure :)